# Count the number of folders in a directory and subdirectories

Tags: python, python-2.7, directory

I've got a script that will accurately tell me how many files are in a directory, and the subdirectories within. However, I'm also looking into identify how many folders there are within the same directory and its subdirectories...

My current script:

```
import os, getpass
from os.path import join, getsize
user = 'Copy of ' + getpass.getuser()
path = "C://Documents and Settings//" + user + "./"
folder_counter = sum([len(folder) for r, d, folder in os.walk(path)])
file_counter = sum([len(files) for r, d, files in os.walk(path)])
print ' [*] ' + str(file_counter) + ' Files were found and ' + str(folder_counter) + ' folders'
```

This code gives me the print out of: `[*] 147 Files were found and 147 folders`.

Meaning that the `folder_counter` isn't counting the right elements. How can I correct this so the `folder_counter` is correct?

Comment: Why are you expecting renaming the third returned value from `os.walk` to give you different results?

Comment: Because I'm new to Python and was hoping it was as simple as that

Comment: But it doesn't make any sense - the function doesn't know what names (if any!) you're assigning the values it returns to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you want something like:

```
import os

files = folders = 0

for _, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
  # ^ this idiom means "we won't be using this value"
    files += len(filenames)
    folders += len(dirnames)

print "{:,} files, {:,} folders".format(files, folders)
```

Note that this only iterates over `os.walk` once, which will make it much quicker on paths containing lots of files and directories. Running it on my Python directory gives me:

```
30,183 files, 2,074 folders
```

which exactly matches what the Windows folder properties view tells me.

---

Note that your current code calculates the same number twice because the *only change* is renaming one of the returned values from the call to `os.walk`:

```
folder_counter = sum([len(folder) for r, d, folder in os.walk(path)])
                        # ^ here          # ^ and here
file_counter = sum([len(files) for r, d, files in os.walk(path)])
                      # ^ vs. here     # ^ and here
```

Despite that name change, you're counting the same value (i.e. in both it's the third of the three returned values that you're using)! Python functions **do not know** what names (if any at all; you could do `print list(os.walk(path))`, for example) the values they return will be assigned to, and their behaviour certainly won't change because of it. Per [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk), `os.walk` returns a three-tuple `(dirpath, dirnames, filenames)`, and the names you use for that, e.g. whether:

```
for foo, bar, baz in os.walk(...):
```

or:

```
for all_three in os.walk(..):
```

won't change that.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for, and thank you for the explanation of how my failed quick simple attempt didn't work!

Answer (score 28):

**Python 2.7 solution**

For a single directory and in you can also do:

```
import os
print len(os.walk('dir_name').next()[1])
```

which will not load the whole string list and also return you the amount of directories inside the `'dir_name'` directory.

**Python 3.x solution**

Since many people just want an easy and fast solution, without actually understanding the solution, I edit my answer to include the exact working code for Python 3.x.

So, in Python 3.x we have the `next` method instead of `.next`. Thus, the above snippet becomes:

```
import os
print(len(next(os.walk('dir_name'))[1]))
```

where `dir_name` is the directory that you want to find out how many directories has inside.

Comment: Crashes on 3.6 with an error: AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'next'

Comment: Of course it crashes in Python 3.x. It is not the problem of the code. Since the topic is about a totally unrelated thing, you will have to read about the differences in Python 3.x and 2.7 and also read and understand the error message that you get.

Comment: Using `[2]` gives the "file count" and `[1]` gives the "folder count"

Answer (score 4):

If interested only in the number of **folders** in /input/dir (and **not in the subdirectories**):

```
import os

folder_count = 0  # type: int
input_path = "/path/to/your/input/dir"  # type: str
for folders in os.listdir(input_path):  # loop over all files
    if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(input_path, folders):  # if it's a directory
        folder_count += 1  # increment counter

print("There are {} folders".format(folder_count))
```

Comment: HI Tommaso, is it possible to count no. of directories in a given path and not subdirectories??

Comment: Hi Nikhil! My answer does exactly what you are asking. It counts only the directories (and not the subdirectories). Maybe post an example so we can discuss further

Comment: above answer is wrong os.listdir returns both directories and files.

Comment: Hi @APPBird ! I modified the answer. Now it only retains directories. However, only for the current dir, and not for the subdirectories

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import os
>>> len(list(os.walk('folder_name')))
```

According to [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) the first argument **dirpath** enumerates all directories.

Comment: This will *only* count the directories, though, and *includes* the root `path` in the count (which may or may not be desirable).

Comment: Isn't counting directories what you want ? I tested the code and it enumerated all directories inside the folder I specified.

 And if you don't need the root path you can subtract 1.

Comment: 1. I'm not the OP. 2. According to the code in the question, they want both.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by both.

Comment: Sorry: both files and folders/directories.

Comment: Okay, I paid more attention to the title.

Comment: In fact this is the answer I was looking for. I've tested it on a linux server with bash command: `find /parent/folder -type d | wc -l` and it give to me same answer as Pyhton code

Answer (score 0):

pathlib provides a convenient way to do this.

```
path = Path('/path/to/your/directory')
files = dirs = 0
for f in path.iterdir():
    if f.is_dir():
        dirs += 1
    elif f.is_file():
        files += 1
```