# Counting subfolders using OS.Walk() in python

Tags: python, os.walk

I would like to learn how to count when os.walk enters into another subfolder. Right now I am able to count the number of files in filenames, but when it switches from the starting directory to another subfolder directory, I would like a count to be added to the subfolder. I am not sure the best way to do this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
count = 0 
subfolder_count = 0 

for foldername, subfolders, filenames in os.walk('articles'):
    for file in filenames:
        if file.endswith('.pdf'):
            count += 1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count the number of folders in a directory and subdirectories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29769181/count-the-number-of-folders-in-a-directory-and-subdirectories)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're already iterating, just keep iterating!

```py
count = 0
subfolder_count = 0

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('articles'):
    for dir_ in dirs:
        subfolder_count += 1
        for file_ in files:
            if file_.endswith('.pdf'):
                count += 1
```

In modern Python (3.4+) you don't even need `os.walk`, because `pathlib` has you covered for the small overhead of traversing the tree twice..

```py
import pathlib

path = pathlib.Path('articles')
subfolder_count = len(path.glob("**/"))
count = len(path.glob("**/*.pdf"))
```

Comment: note: there may be an off-by-one error here. `path.glob("**/")` might include the root which the `os.walk` method would not